# Getting data with UTF-8 charset from MSSQL server using PHP FreeTDS extension

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8, freetds

I can't seem to get data from MSSQL encoded as UTF-8 using FreeTDS extension.

Connecting:

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
$this->_resource = mssql_connect($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
```

I have no ability to use any other extension.

I've tried creating ~/.freetds.conf

```
[global]
client charset = UTF-8
```

I've tried passing parameters to php:

```
php -d mssql.charset="UTF-8" index.php
```

Data is still not in UTF-8.

php -i

```
mssql

MSSQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Library version => FreeTDS

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mssql.allow_persistent => On => On
mssql.batchsize => 0 => 0
mssql.charset => no value => no value
mssql.compatability_mode => Off => Off
mssql.connect_timeout => 5 => 5
mssql.datetimeconvert => On => On
mssql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mssql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MSSQL and UTF-8 are quite a pain in the ... sometimes. I had to convert it manually.
The problem: MSSQL doesn't actually know and support UTF-8.

Convert from database value to UTF-8:

```
mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8' ? $value : mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8');
```

Converting from UTF-8 to database value:

```
mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UCS-2LE', mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true));
```

Fortunately I was using Doctrine so all I had was to create a custom StringType implementation.

Comment: MS SqlServer uses UCS2-LE encoding, not CP1252. Not ISO8859-1 (subset of CP1252) either. Not UTF-16 (came after UCS2) or 'Unicode' (WideChar/UTF-16 on Win) either.

Comment: You saved my life. I will answer my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977752/invalid-column-name-column-accents-in-ms-sql-server/) on how to use it with CodeIgniter

Answer (score 31):

I had a similar problem and tried all settings i could find on the web - in vain.

In my case the problem was the configuration of FreeTDS itself. On Linux the file is /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

I had to change the Version to 7.0 (maybe other numbers work, too. i just tried 7.0)

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
    tds version = 7.0
```

After this, the driver seemed to accept changes of the charset like.

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Btw: the change immediately is in effect, no need to restart anything afterwards

Comment: million of thanks to @user1903844. This solutions helped me with Ubuntu+MS SQL+PHP

Comment: Version >= 7.0 is required to set the config option `client charset = UTF-8` which might be why OP Marius Grigaitis's solution using it didn't work. See this gist for `freetds.conf` example: https://gist.github.com/johnkary/6643856

Comment: Yey, finally a working answer! Uncommented line, changed value to 7.0 and it worked. Didn't need the `ini_set` part.

Comment: Great. Working! Probably FreeTDS version 7.0 supports automatic conversion between client format (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or something else) and UCS2-LE (the MSSQL charset), so this is transparent to the programmer.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me on Xenial Xerus, PHP 7, MSSQL 2008, FreeTDS v0.91

Answer (score 16):

If you use freeTDS, you should change below lines on `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`:

```
[global]
# TDS protocol version
tds version = 4.2
```

To this:

```
[global]
# TDS protocol version
tds version = 8.0
;tds version = 4.2
```

and finally add this line:

```
# set charset
client charset = UTF-8
```

** clinet charset is in global [scope]

In your queries, you should use N character. like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.SMSOutbox (StationID, Dest, Text) VALUES ";
   $query .= '(';
   $query .= "'" . $this->stationId . "', ";
   $query .= "'" . $this->destination . "', ";
   $query .= "N'" . $this->text . "'";
   $query .= ')';
```

Comment: This solved it for me, combined with the conversions by @louis-huppenbauer.

Answer (score 15):

You can also solve this issue by adding CharacterSet UTF-8 in the $connectionInfo before connecting to the DB.

```
$serverName = "MyServer";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AdventureWorks", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Worked fine NO additional encoding needed.

Comment: I cant believe that this is not the accepted answer, worked just fine and its so easy to do. if i could give you more than just +1 i would

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this answer, I looked all over for a solution and this works perfectly.

Comment: I totally agree; this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This answer is correct for the SQLSRV library from Microsoft but isn't correct for FreeTDS library which the author specifically asked about.

Answer (score 2):

It seem version 7.0 or great is required. iconv() also seems to work well, but is tedious.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    foreach (get_object_vars($row) as $key => $value) {
    $row->$key = (mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8') 
            ? $value : iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', $value);
    }
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: This works! I'm saying because sometimes people ignore answers without too much votes.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it solved by adding this line to my php script before connecting to MSSQL Server:

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your TDS version based on what version of SQL server your using.
Check out the installation guide for details.

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Answer (score 0):

I used same as above but windows 1250, so:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    foreach (get_object_vars($row) as $key => $value) {
    $row->$key = (mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8') 
            ? $value : iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $value);
    }
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

And then it worked, but I use polish characters