# Convert French_CI_AS (ASCII) to UTF8

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I would like to convert data from SQL Server (ASCII) to UTF-8.

When I use the query :

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

The result is 'French_CI_AS' (So, ASCII)

When I use DBAL from Symfony to get users from a remote database, and then, show them, it appears that the accents looks like that :

Ang�lina

I tried :

```
utf8_encode($value)
```

but it's only for ISO-8859-1...

So I tried :

```
iconv("French_CI_AS", "UTF-8", $value)
```

Or :

```
iconv("ASCII", "UTF-8", $value)
```

but it doesn't seems to work...

My meta template is :

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

So, any idea to convert the user names from ASCII to UTF-8 ?

Comment: [Collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) is not encoding.

Comment: I don't understand the difference. When I Googled 'how to know which encoding is used in MS SQL' it returns me many results with people use Collation to know that...

Comment: Encoding is how text is stored. Collation is how text is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII cannot store [French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_orthography), as far as I know. [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174596%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) suggests that French_CI_AS uses Windows-1252 as encoding. Try that instead.

In any case, your DB library should take care of that automatically. You've probably failed to provide the connection encoding.

Comment: using iconv("WINDOWS-1252", "UTF-8", $value); or mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252"); didn't change anything... Or maybe I falied something ?
I use Symfony and a config.yml file but if I write charset: UTF8 it doesn't change anything. I'm on a Debian, I use a MS SQL driver for Linux to connect to the remote database...

Comment: Please check [Getting data with UTF-8 charset from MSSQL server using PHP FreeTDS extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377812/getting-data-with-utf-8-charset-from-mssql-server-using-php-freetds-extension)