# Insert to Remote Mssql Server From Ubuntu 16.01 Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I'm using Laravel Forge + Digital Ocean for server solutions. Forge created default server on Digital Ocean.

When I insert remote mssql from my localhost (Ubuntu 14.04 PHP 5.6 Apache2) everything is fine. But when I insert remote mssql from production server (Laravel Forge + Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.01 PHP 7 - NGINX) I'm getting character encoding problem.

It looks like Chinese.

[image]

Mssql 'collation' => 'Turkish_CI_AS'

And I applied all instructions [in here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/sqlsrv-driver-on-linux/replies/14216) for both servers. What am i doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1254' , $value)
```

I returned default configurations and I applied this iconv solution. But it is not working too.

Comment: I found the solution in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377935/2773954 Thank you.