# Invalid column name, column accents in MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, collation

I'm currently working with an old database that has column names containing accents. When I try to execute this query in Codeigniter (PHP):

```
SELECT *
FROM [empresas] [em]
LEFT JOIN [clientes] [cl] ON [em].[empresa] = [cl].[Código]
```

The system throws the error

> "Invalid column name 'Código'". (the column name is 'Código')

I've tried using `COLLATE` function with no success.

The MS SQL Server database default collation is `Modern_Spanish_CI_AI` and the column collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

How can I solve this problem?

Codeigniter has a configuration field name "dbcollation" that sets the collation used to communicate with the database but I don't know if it affects in this problem (I've tested some values with no success too).

Thank you.

Comment: just as a workaround try to create a view or synonyms from db

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your database collection into utf8_general_ci

Comment: It's not my database, that's why I don't convert it. I always use utf8_general_ci, it's better to cover this type of issues. Thanks anyway :P