# Viewing German words on webpage

Tags: php, html, sql-server, unicode

I got a MS SQL table for translation of my webpagel, when I change my language to german there are words what are not shows properly an example in DB:

```
EL_ID   TEXT_EN TEXT_DE
el10    Reset   Löschen
```

but when I use in my html/php page it is not showing properly:

```
[10] => Array
        (
            [0] => el10
            [1] => L�schen
        )
```

in my webpage I got activated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <TITLE>
    </TITLE>
...
```

It is the data what is carried out from the `DB` or the `HTML` presentation the issue?

Comment: https://phpbestpractices.org/#utf-8 - to put it short, your encoding is wrong. should display a german umlaut.

Comment: I was using ADODB for DB connection I needed to insert in my connection string the following parameter `$db->setConnectionParameter('CharacterSet','UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql) to be a good resource for any case of encoding problems:

- For HTML content, specify UTF-8 as the encoding:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  ```
- Set UTF-8 as the default character set for all database connections. It however looks like MSSQL [doesn't really support UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13377935/710921).

Comment: I resolved the issue, because I am using ADODB I needed to set the right parameter for db connection `$db->setConnectionParameter('CharacterSet','UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

Three questions:

- what is the type of column TEXT_DE?? Should be nvarchar or ntext
- how did you add value in column TEXT_DE - copy & paste from file - maybe file was saved in different coding system
- what is collation of DB or that table? Run below queries

  `SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));`

  `SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;`

Comment: I found the solution I am using ADODB needed to insert `$db->setConnectionParameter('CharacterSet','UTF-8');`